# When searching Global Address List, is there a way to do a partial search and not just a "startsWith"

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have the following code to search the global address book by a certain string:

"CONF"

```
var esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
esb.Url = @"https://myurl.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user,_pwd, _domain);

var rnType = new ResolveNamesType {ReturnFullContactData = true, UnresolvedEntry = "CONF"};

ResolveNamesResponseType response = esb.ResolveNames(rnType);
ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responses = resolveNamesResponse.ResponseMessages;
var responseMessage = responses.Items[0] as ResolveNamesResponseMessageType;

ResolutionType[] resolutions = responseMessage.ResolutionSet.Resolution;
```

the issue is that it seems to be doing a "starts with" search so I have a name called:

"CONF-123" it will show up but if i have a name "JOE-CONF" then it will not.

How can I do a partial string search on this line

```
var rnType = new ResolveNamesType {ReturnFullContactData = true, UnresolvedEntry = "CONF-"};
```

i was hoping there was something like:

```
var rnType = new ResolveNamesType {ReturnFullContactData = true, UnresolvedEntry = "%CONF-%"};
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your looking for 'CONF-', but stating that 'JOE-CONF' doesn't show up in the return.  I wouldn't think it would given that the '-' is after the 'CONF', what happens if you just use 'CONF' without the '-'.

Comment: that was a typo . .  i have updated the question

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** Jan 4,2016 - Added sample code for searching AD.

**What won't work**

Searching the GAL via ResolveNames always uses prefix-string match for Ambiguous Name Resolution (ARN). Although EWS documentation does not say this explicitly, the Exchange ActiveSync documentation does. EWS and Exchange ActiveSync are just protocols; they both rely on ARN underneath, so you are stuck with prefix match, whether you use ActiveSync protocol or EWS.

Here is the relevant quote from Exchange ActiveSync documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee159743%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

> The text query string that is provided to the Search command is used
>   in a prefix-string match

.

**What will work**

The best thing to do depends on your use case, but here are some ideas:

Search Active Directory in your client program (the program that contains the code you showed in your question)

Set up your own service to search the GAL. Your client program would connect both to Exchange and to your service. Or your service could proxy EWS, so that the client program needs to connect only to your service.

How would you service get the GAL data? One way would be to use EWS ResolveNames repeatedly, to get the GAL data, 100 entries at a time and cache this data in your service. First, retrieve all the "a"s, then all the "b"s, etc. Of course, there can be more than 100 "a"s in the GAL, so just getting all the "a"s could take multiple searches - you would construct your next search string, based on the last entry returned from each search. This can be slow and painful. You would probably want to cache this data in a database and refresh it periodically.

You can also get to GAL through MAPI. You can use MAPI directly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765775%28v=office.12%29.aspx) or through a helper library like Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm). Whether you use MAPI directly or through Redemption, you will need to install Outlook (or Exchange) on the computer where your code is running. Because of this restriction, it may be best to not use MAPI in your client program, but to stick it in a service running on some server and have your client program connect to that service.

**AD Code Sample**

Another answer provided sample code to search Active Directory. I am adding a code sample that may be better suited for generic use by people who may find this question through search. Compared to the other sample, the code below has the following improvements:

- If the search string contains any special characters (like parenthesis), they are escaped, so that the constructed filter string is valid.
- Searching by just samaccountname many not be sufficient. If "David Smith" has account name "dsmith", searching for "David" by samaccountname would not find him. My sample shows how to search by more fields and gives some of the fields one may want to search.
- Starting at a root like "GC:" is more robust than trying to construct an LDAP entry from Domain.GetComputerDomain().
- All `IDisposable`s must be disposed of (usually by using them in a `using` construct).

  ```
  // Search Active Directory users.
  public static IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> SearchADUsers(string search) {
      // Escape special characters in the search string.
      string escapedSearch = search.Replace("*", "\\2a").Replace("(", "\\28")
          .Replace(")", "\\29").Replace("/", "\\2f").Replace("\\", "\\5c");

      // Find entries where search string appears in ANY of the following fields
      // (you can add or remove fields to suit your needs).
      // The '|' characters near the start of the expression means "any".
      string searchPropertiesExpression = string.Format(
          "(|(sn=*{0}*)(givenName=*{0}*)(cn=*{0}*)(dn=*{0}*)(samaccountname=*{0}*))",
          escapedSearch);

      // Only want users
      string filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(" + searchPropertiesExpression + "))"; 

      using (DirectoryEntry gc = new DirectoryEntry("GC:")) {
          foreach (DirectoryEntry root in gc.Children) {
              try {
                  using (DirectorySearcher s = new DirectorySearcher(root, filter)) {
                      s.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
                      SearchResultCollection results = s.FindAll();
                      foreach (SearchResult result in results) {
                          using (DirectoryEntry de = result.GetDirectoryEntry()) {
                              yield return de;
                          }
                      }
                  }
              } finally {
                  root.Dispose();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I appreciate you have shared better implementation of AD Search. But please be nice/polite & instead use words like "to improve the above answer", "to add to it", etc. I urge you not to use words/sound like "Above answer has many shortcomings", "My answer is better". Everyone here is to help, learn from each other. There's no doubt that any piece of code has scope for improvement. The crux of problem leora is facing is to search with contains match. I tried to answer it, rather than focusing on writing the most efficient code, which I believe leora won't have any problem writing.

Comment: You are right, Abhijit. Thanks for teaching me proper manners. I edited my wording.

Answer (score 4):

Though wildcard search isn't possible in EWS, it is possible in AD search. AD Queries support wildcards. i.e., *CONF* can be searched in AD, which will return all results which contain "CONF". Based on the results, query EWS for an corresponding Exchange Object. You need to find a parameter with which you can find the corresponding EWS entry. I guess email address (username) should be sufficient to find the corresponding exchange object.

AD Search code snippet...

```
private SearchResultCollection SearchByName(string username, string password, string searchKeyword)
{
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Domain.GetComputerDomain().ToString().ToLower(), username, password));
    ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=*" + searchKeyword + "*))";
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.ServerTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
    return ds.FindAll();
}
```

AD Query Example [here](http://myjeeva.com/querying-active-directory-using-csharp.html).

Answer (score 0):

An ambiguous search on an indexed text field can only be done with prefix (or suffix...). That's why Exchange probably implements the query as LIKE 'CONF%'.

I've looked over the documentation and there isn't any way you can bypass it - full table scan (which would have to be the case for %CONF%) does not seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to search the GAL from PHP using php-ews. On a web page the user starts to enter the name to be searched, once 2 chars have been entered a call to read_contacts.php is made passing the 2 chars entered. read_contacts.php uses EWS ResolveNames request to retrieve a limited list of contacts. The code then filters on some criteria and also checks that the displayName starts with the chars entered. This then returns the filtered list:

```
<?php
$staffName = $_GET['q'];    
require_once './php-ews/EWSType.php';
require_once './php-ews/ExchangeWebServices.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/RestrictionType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/ContainsExpressionType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/PathToUnindexedFieldType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/ConstantValueType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/ContainmentModeType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/ResolveNamesType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/EWSType/ResolveNamesSearchScopeType.php';
require_once 'php-ews/NTLMSoapClient.php';
require_once 'php-ews/NTLMSoapClient/Exchange.php';

$host = '[exchange server]';
$user = '[exchange user]'; 
$password = '[exchange password]';

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host,  $user, $password);

$request = new EWSType_ResolveNamesType();

$request->ReturnFullContactData = true;
$request->UnresolvedEntry = $staffName;


$displayName = '';
$i = 0;
$staff_members = false;
$response = $ews->ResolveNames($request);
if ($response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResponseClass == 'Error' && $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->MessageText == 'No results were found.') {
}
else {
    $numNamesFound = $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResolutionSet->TotalItemsInView;
    $i2=0;
    for ($i=0;$i<$numNamesFound;$i++) {
        if ($numNamesFound == 1) {
            $displayName = $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResolutionSet->Resolution->Contact->DisplayName;
        }
        else {
            $displayName = $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResolutionSet->Resolution[$i]->Contact->DisplayName;
        }
        echo "DisplayName: " . $displayName . "\n";     
        if (stripos($displayName, 'External') == true) {
        }
        else {
            $searchLen = strlen($staffName);
            if (strcasecmp(substr($displayName, 0, $searchLen), $staffName) == 0) {
                if ($numNamesFound == 1) {
                    $emailAddress = $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResolutionSet->Resolution->Mailbox->EmailAddress;
                }
                else {
                    $emailAddress = $response->ResponseMessages->ResolveNamesResponseMessage->ResolutionSet->Resolution[$i]->Mailbox->EmailAddress;
                }
                $staff_members[$i2] = array( 'name' => $displayName,'email' => $emailAddress );
                $i2++;
            }
        }
    }
    $staffJson = json_encode($staff_members);
echo $staffJson;
}
```

Most of the time this seems to work, ie: 'mi', 'jo' returns Mike, Michael, or Joe, John, except when I sent 'Si' or 'si', for Simon, then  the ResolveNames call returns the first 100 entries from the GAL.

For the time being I have increased the minimum number of characters to be entered to 3, ie: 'sim' and this works. The problem will be when we get staff with only 2 character first names.

I just thought I would share the code to see if it helps and to see if anyone knows why my 'si' does not work properly.

I am accessing Exchange 2010